# I'm writing an email to an investor. Please help me to improve my sentences

Tags: american-english, email, letter-writing, subcontinental-english, professions

I am sending a detailed document about our idea, as requested by an investor. Are the sentences correct? Do they need any improvement?

> As per our conversation yesterday, I am sending you a detailed
>   description of our idea. Please find it in attached PDF document.
>   Hoping for your positive feedback on this.

Comment: That's absolutely fine as it is. If I received that then I'd find it very sensible and clear.

Comment: @A E Agreed. I can't help but edit (especially if invited) but the original is not bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an American with some experience in this style I would write:

> As per our conversation yesterday, please find attached a PDF document containing a detailed description of our idea for your review. I am looking forward to your positive feedback.
>
> Regards, [or: Thank you for your consideration, or something like that]
>
> XXX.

The phrase "please find attached X" is a fixed phrase used in business correspondence, don't worry if it sounds a little strange. The whole thing is wordy and a little bit redundant, but that's formal writing for you. You can trim it down to make it less formal.

The last sentence might be too pushy; I would remove the word "positive" to take a more moderate tone.

Comment: @Aishwarya Shiva I suggest using the date of the conversation rather than saying "yesterday". The investor might not see the email for several days.

Answer (score -1):

> As per our discussion yesterday, I have prepared a detail document on our idea. Please find the attachment for the same.
>
> Let me know if I missed anything.
>
> Thanks,
>       XXX

Comment: OP's original "a detailed description of our idea" sounds better to me than your "a detail document on our idea", TBH. "Please find the attachment for the same" also sounds worse than the OP's original "Please find it in attached PDF document" to me - sorry.

Comment: The otiose "as per" can always be replaced with the simpler "per" — and should be.